# Currently is there any proof that Mael have used "The ONE" form?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Is there anyone can proof that Mael have used "THE ONE" form in the 3000 years ago?

I wonder how many PL he could reach when he activate that form.

Comment: It might help future answerers to connect the dot by explaining some background/relevant links to this, that "The One" form is a form of [Sunshine](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Sunshine) that Escanor has shown, and the power was previously given to Mael 3000 years ago.

Comment: It's seems like the info is still unknown for Mael right?  well gonna wait for it...